# What is the appropriate way to define simple ES6 component classes?

Tags: javascript, es6-class

I'm trying to built several simple components, such as alerts, tabs, dialogs, using only ES6, and I'm finding it difficult to find out if there is some standard method for defining the necessary JavaScript classes.

My code is presented below; it works, but I have no idea if this is the appropriate way for doing this. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
class Notice {
  select() {
    this.notices = document.querySelectorAll(".c-notice");
    this.notices.forEach(notice => {
      notice.addEventListener("click", () => {
        this.dismiss(event.target.closest(".c-notice"));
      });
    });
  }
  dismiss(element) {
    element.classList.add("u-display-none");
  }
}

let notice = new Notice();
notice.select();

export default Notice;
```

Comment: The closest thing to a standard is https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/custom-elements.html#custom-elements but that's currently non-normative

Comment: Thank you. There are some interesting tidbits presented in the spec, but I find the examples listed there too generic. I'm interested to know if selecting elements (`document.querySelectorAll(".c-notice")`) should happen outside the class definition, if event delegation should be achieved via a separate method, and other similar prescriptions.

Comment: Matter of opinion.